# refreshing a scene between levels in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d in my game, i need to reload all scene when level complete.
My game is in **one** class `helloWorldLayer.mm` , and it has conditions to load different backgrounds for different levels.
What i want is that when level complete,i **increment** the level by 1 , and load the whole scene again( the init) , so the new backgrounds and sprites will reloaded.

What is the best way to do that ??

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose u are loading the data from plist .

what u have to do is remove all the items from the scene and then call your loadingplist function and recreate the layer.

You can have a singleton to store your level count , once the game is completed increment the value in the singleton then retrive the value later to recreate the next level.

Hope this helps ..